# Pass the page number to a server side datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am using datatable with Laravel to order a response that i receive from an API

I connect to the API with this code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.turn14.com/v1/items?page=$page');
```

How you can see i just need to add the $page and it starts to take me all the products from their page, if i add page=1 it takes all the values of the API from the page 1, etc etc

The thing is that I am using datatable server side because i want to use all the functionalities that it offers me BUT I do not know how can i pass the number page with the datatable, I mean if I push the number 2 in the button how can i get that value?

I mean in the paginator says 1 .. 2 .. 3 etc, if i push 2 how can i know that i pushed in the button 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know more about your code. That said, from what I can understand, when you pass the page number to the url - you receive the next page with data from the endpoint. If you are using the Laravel paginator and not something custom, the usual way it works is that it appends a query parameter to the current url:

Imagine you have a controller **HomeController** with a method **index**:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function index(Request $request) {
      dd($request->get('page')); // this will return your current page

      // Make sure you check the page query parameter first before using it like this.
      $ch = curl_init('https://api.turn14.com/v1/items?page='.$request->get('page'));

      return view('home');
    }
```

For more information you can read the Laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#basic-usage

> By default, the current page is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request. This value is automatically detected by Laravel, and is also automatically inserted into links generated by the paginator.